# Can a Java class implement a C++ interface

Tags: java, c++, interface

Is it possible to a Java class to implement a C++ interface (interface meaning a full abstract class)?
Where can I read more about?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  Java has the concept of "interface" too, as well as abstract classes. Visit http://java.sun.com maybe ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no. However, you can create a C++ implementation of that interface that simply delegates to a Java implementation via JNI. See the [JNI Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

[Here's](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) a tutorial from Sun / Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Not in the general sense, no. C++ classes do not exist in the compiled binary the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Well, they do exist in the sense that they export symbols in the compiled binaries (their plain methods, and typically their virtual table pointers and virtual methods). Linkers and BridJ make use of these exported symbols to wire C++ or Java programs to the compiled C++ classes. The exception would be COM, which does not export anything through symbols but rather through an API.

Comment: @zOlive: No -- actually they don't have to export anything in the compiled binaries. If the method gets inlined everywhere there's no gaurentee that it'll exist in the compiled binary at all.

Comment: Methods get inlined by default only if their body is defined in the header, which is generally not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Support for overriding virtual C++ methods is planned in [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) (a JNA alternative that supports C++), but it's not there yet.

***Update:*** As of [version 0.4](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/downloads/list), **BridJ supports implementing C++ interfaces from Java** :

Consider the following C++ class :

```
#ifndef TEST_EXPORTS
#define TEST_EXPORTS
#endif
class TEST_EXPORTS TestClass {
public:
    virtual int add(int a, int b);
};
```

You'd bind this class from Java with these BridJ bindings :

```
public class TestClass extends CPPObject { 
    @Virtual(0) 
    public native int add(int a, int b); 
};
```

And would be able to subclass your C++ class from Java very naturally :

```
TestClass test = new TestClass() { 
    @Override 
    public int add(int a, int b) { 
        return a + b; 
    } 
};
```

Comment: Note that `virtual` here is not optional -- it forces the compiler to emit the function symbol in the binary, and prevents the compiler from inlining the function out of the binary completely. Also note that BirdJ supports GCC 4.x and MSVC 9 only (Don't even know where they got a version of MSVC 9 -- the current version is version 16)

Comment: One could perfectly do without the virtual keyword here, provided the method body is not defined in the header (which would be bad practice anyway, in general). The purpose of a header is to indicate which symbols can be resolved in the corresponding library. With virtual methods, you don't need to export the symbol, you just need to know it's position in the virtual table (which can be computed by looking at the class definition in the header).

Comment: @zOlive: Not true -- that depends on the compiler. MSVC in release mode will inline across translation units, and I believe recent builds of GCC can do so as well. (This is not in any way related to the C++ `inline` specifier -- it's related to optimizations that compilers make -- remember that `inline` (along with the implicit header `inline` you describe) is only a hint, not a requirement, and compilers are free to inline or not inline as they see fit)

Comment: As far as virtual methods go, making the method virtual means that it has to exist as a real method, so that it can be called (because the compiler cannot prove at the call site which one will be called, which is the point of making it virtual in the first place).

Comment: I suppose you could force the compiler to include a symbol that does what you want (i.e. with `__declspec` on MSVC or `__attribute__` on GCC), but even in that case exporting C++ classes is a Bad Idea because it's too easy to break the one definition rule (i.e. different compiler switches or compiler versions change how exceptions, name mangling, parameter passing, padding, member ordering, and such work) -- and undefined behavior is bad, m'kay? :)

Comment: Hehe, sorry for the misunderstanding : I assumed the common convention of `TEST_EXPORTS` being defined as `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`, as is done automatically from MSVC++'s  "new C++ project" wizard. I'm of course talking about C++ libraries that could be linked to by a thirdparty C++ program (the problem is the same for a linker and for BridJ).

Comment: And exporting C++ classes is just the only way to make your library useable by a C++ program in a C++ way, when static linking is not an option. Great libraries like OpenCV switched to having C++ interfaces, and MFC does work well also...

Comment: @zOlive: That is true. If you are using C++ exports though, take care: You must use the **EXACT SAME** compiler **version** and **switches** for *every* related linked library. Otherwise you will usually incur undefined behavior (if nothing else because different switches change things like CRTs and calling conventions) (C++ doesn't have a standard ABI, which sucks, but so long as it doesn't one has to be extremely careful)

Answer (score 0):

Besides JNI there's another technology named [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). It seems to be simpler (no need to create C/C++ stub code).

Answer (score -1):

Java class can implement Java interface. Java/C++ communication is done using JNI.